# mongodb + remote access

Tags: mongodb

I've installed mongodb on Linux(CenOS) server as it's written in [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Unix). But still remote access is impossible (although conecting from mongo shell locally is ok). Can someone provide docs on proper configuring of mongodb?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I install it on a Debian, and I did not  have any problem. Do you have any firewall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either running behind a firewall or mongod is bound to localhost only (use --bind-ip option to configure the IP address if necessary).

Answer (score 13):

Source: [MongoDb setup config to connect by remote hosts](http://blog.aeonmedia.eu/2011/04/mongodb-setup-config-to-connect-by-remote-hosts-debian/)

On ubuntu:

`root@debian:$ sudo nano /etc/mongodb.conf`

Make sure you have the following lines

`bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
port = 27017`

`root@debian:$ /etc/init.d/mongodb restart`

Comment: the accepted answer is correct, but this one is more specific and helped me out! port is default 27017 and shouldn't be commented out. just commenting # bind_ip = 127.0.0.1 did the trick for me

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/mongodb.conf` should be `sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: Worked for me! How do I set a username and password for remote connections?